# How do I find $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ if $a_{2n}=\frac {a_{2n-1}}2$ and $a_{2n+1}=\frac12+\frac {a_{2n}}2$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations, limsup-and-liminf

Its given that $a_1=a>0$ and that for any $n>1$ two things happen:
$$a_{2n}=\frac {a_{2n-1}}2$$
$$a_{2n+1}=\frac12+\frac {a_{2n}}2$$

How do I find $\lim\inf$ and $\lim\sup$
I am trying to look at

$a_{2n+1}$ and $a_{2n-1}$
$a_{2n}$ and $a_{2n-2}$

But I am unable to prove that they are bounded.

NOTE: Look at joeys answer for correct solution.

Comment: Say $a_i>10$ (for no real reason, could've been $4$ or $100$) for some $i$. In that case, show that no matter whether $i$ is even or odd, we have $a_{i+1}<\frac{2a_i}{3}$, but still positive. That should take care of the boundedness. If you want to look at every other term, then $a_{2i} < \frac{a_{2i-2}}3$ and $a_{2i+1}<\frac{a_{2i-1}}3$ should work as well.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: This response was written for the recurrence equations
$$ a_{2n} = \frac{a_{2n-1}}{2}, a_{2n+1} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{a_{2n}}{2}. $$
The exact answer may differ depending on the exact edit to the question, but the techniques remain valid, assuming the coefficients are not drastically changed.

---

Since there are different rules for the even and odd terms, it makes sense to suspect that the even terms will behave differently from the odd terms. So let's investigate the two sets of terms separately.

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, let $b_n = a_{2n-1}$ and $c_n = a_{2n}$. From the relations provided, we have
$$ b_{n+1} = a_{2n+1} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{a_{2n}}{2} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{a_{2n-1}}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{b_{n}}{4}$$
Similarly, we have
$$ c_{n+1} = a_{2n+2} = \frac{a_{2n+1}}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{a_{2n}}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{c_n}{4}.$$

We now look at the behavior of $b_n$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Suppose it converged to some value, say $b$. What would $b$ have to be? If we take our equation
$$ b_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{b_n}{4} $$
and let $n\rightarrow\infty$, then both $b_{n+1}$ and $b_n$ would converge to $b$, and hence
$$ b = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{b}{4}\implies b=\frac{2}{3}.$$
So we have a hunch that $b_n$ converges to $\frac{2}{3}$. How do we prove it? Well, let $d_n = b_n - \frac{2}{3}$, and let's try to show that $d_n\rightarrow 0$. Now,
$$ b_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{b_n}{4}\implies d_n + \frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{d_n + \frac{2}{3}}{4} = \frac{2}{3} + \frac{d_n}{4}\implies d_{n+1} = \frac{d_n}{4}$$
which clearly shows that $d_n\rightarrow 0$. Hence, $b_n\rightarrow\frac{2}{3}$. Similar reasoning yields that $c_n\rightarrow c$, where
$$ c = \frac{1}{4} +\frac{c}{4}\implies c = \frac{1}{3}.$$

Hence, the odd terms tend to $\frac{2}{3}$, and the even terms tend to $\frac{1}{3}$. This shows that
$$ \limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a_n} = \frac{2}{3} $$
and
$$ \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a_n} = \frac{1}{3}. $$

Comment: Hello , first I updated the question there was a mistake, second shouldnt you show monotonic and bounded?

Comment: @TommyKad First of all, are you sure the updated version is correct? Seeing $\frac{a_{2n}}{1}$ is very weird (why not just $a_{2n}$?). But if it is correct, then this method would still give you valid results (just change the numbers). Secondly, showing that a sequence is monotonic and bounded is just one way to show that a sequence converges. In your case, $a_n$ is not monotone, and in fact your sequence doesn't even converge. The subsequences $b_n$ and $c_n$ (as defined above) are, however, monotone and bounded, and so they do converge (although I showed that another way).

Comment: Hey, I have checked again, in all of your answer you are using limits arithmatics;and for that the sequence has to converge,but you didnt prove that!

Comment: @TommyKad I proved that the sequence $\{b_n\}$ converges. I did this by first finding out what it had to converge to (this part should be treated informally--I basically said "if we assume some things, what do we get?"). But then I proved formally that $b_n$ converges to $\frac{2}{3}$. Let me know if you have trouble finding where I proved this or trouble understanding the proof.

Comment: Ok i will check again

Comment: Hey,look,after we show that dn converges then the following proves bn also converges: since dn=bn-2/3 and dn goes to zero then bn-2/3 also  goes to zero, its true that bn=(bn-2/3)+2/3,2/3 is a const sequence then it converges to 2/3,  then if n goes to infinity then from bn=(bn-2/3)+2/3 according to arithmatic the sum of two converging sequences is equal to the limit of the two converging sequences and since bn-2/3 goes to zero and 2/3 goes to 2/3 then the limit goes to their sum which is 0+2/3 =2/3 thus limit bn= 2/3, and this showes that bn is convergent and its limit is 2/3.  Q.E.D

Comment: Thank you very much, your a life saviour!!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the limsup from a recursive formula, which is how it has been given in the problem statement. However, through an inductive proof, an explicit formula for the terms of this sequence can be found:

$a_{2n} = \frac {1}{2}  - \frac{1}{2^n}$

$a_{2n+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^n}$

Taking the limits of both of these subsequences gives $\frac{1}{2}$ and 1, respectively.

The limsup $a_n$ is ≥ 1. (Since we have a subsequence converging to 1, and the limsup is the biggest subsequential limit, it can not be less than 1.)  Further, the only two subsequential limits we can get are  1 and 1/2. So the limsup is 1.

This is because these two subsequences together contain all of the terms of $a_n$, (that is, every term in the sequence $a_n$  is either $a_{2n} $ and $a_{2n+1}$ , since n is either even or odd).

An alternative way to think of this is that the set of subsequential limits is the set {$1 , \frac{1}{2}$}. Every convergent subsequence converges to one of these two values. Then, the supremum of this set is 1, so limsup $a_n$ is 1.

Answer (score -1):

It could of course be that I made a mistake in my calculations so proceed with caution!

We'll show by induction that for any $n \geq 1$:
$$
a_{2n} =  \frac{a}{2\cdot 4^n} + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{4^i}
$$
where a sum $\sum_{i=1}^0\frac{1}{4^n}$ is assumed to be zero.

The first step: $n=1$ is trivial. Now let $n$ be arbitrary we'll first prove the form of $a_{2(n+1)}$: by the induction hypethesis we may assume that:
$
a_{2n} =\frac{a}{2\cdot 4^n} + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{4^i}
$ thus we get:
$$
a_{2(n+1)} = a_{2n+2} = \frac{a_{2n+1}}{2} = \frac{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{a_{2n}}{2}}{2} = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{a_{2n}}{4} \overset{IH}{=}  \frac{1}{4} + \frac{\frac{a}{2\cdot 4^n} + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{4^i}}{4} \\= \frac{1}{4} + \frac{a}{2\cdot 4^{n+1}} + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{4^{i+1}}= \frac{a}{2\cdot 4^{n+1}} + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{4^{i}}
$$
which proves the claimed equality for $a_{2n}$ we now have for arbitrary $n$:
$$
a_{2n+1} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{a_{2n}}{2} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\frac{a}{2\cdot 4^n} + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{4^n}}{2} = \frac{a}{4^{n+1}} + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{4^i}.$$
Can you deduce the result from this? I can work it out further if you want but I think it's clear how you should continue now (just calculating the sums yields that the liminf is 1/3 and the limsup is 2/3).

Now without liminf and limsup, first we show that $a_n \geq 1/3 $ always holds by induction. For $a_{2n+1}$ this is immediately clear since we have $a_{2n+1} \geq 1/2$. For $a_{2n}$ we proceed by induction so suppose we have $a_{2n} \geq 1/3$ and we show that then also $a_{2(n+1)} \geq 1/3$, we have:
$$
a_{2(n+1)} = a_{2n + 2} = \frac{a_{2n-1}}{2} = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{a_{2n}}{4} \geq \frac{1}{4} + \frac{\frac{1}{3}}{4} = 1/3,
$$
in the same way one shows that $a_n \leq 2/3$ for all $n$. Now it remains to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{2n} \leq 1/3$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_{2n+1} \geq 2/3$ if you show this you are done.

Comment: Hello, we didnt learn to use sums like these, we learnt induction with sequences but not using sums, can you show it by showing that the sequence is bounded and montonic without using sums?

Comment: Hmm that's a bit weird but let me check

Comment: Ok so I showed the boundedness and gave a hint for showing the rest of your claim without using sums below my "sum answer" ;)

Comment: Ok I will check it. Thanks

Comment: Hello I wanted to add that the sequences are defined only for n strictly bigger than one.

Comment: I added it in my explanation, I explicitly write that the sum that goes from 1 to zero is assumed to be 0 this is just for notational comfort